# INSERT IF NOT EXISTS with NULL value

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, exists

I have two tables: tags and linking table photos_tags. I want to add a new tag, so I check if the tag is already in the tags table and if not I insert one. My tables look something like this: tags(id, name), photos_tags(photos_id, tags_id). Now I tried to do this with:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name=*tagsName*)  
  INSERT INTO tags VALUES (NULL, *tagsName*); --NULL used for autonumbering
```

I've also tried:

```
INSERT INTO tags (  
  SELECT NULL, *tagsName*  
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
    SELECT * FROM tags  
    WHERE name=*tagsName*  
  )  
);
```

Both statements result in syntax errors:

- in the first statement near `if`
- in the second statement near `select`

What should my query look like?

Comment: By the way, `*tagsName*` this is not valid and should look like `'tagsName'`. At first I thought you just wrote it like that but now I am worried you made a mistake here.

Comment: In the first statement: near "IF": syntax error
In the second: near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: don't worry, it's replaced with \'"+ tag +"\'

Comment: Shouldn't your strings be wrapped in single ticks?
    'tagsName' instead of *tagsname*

Comment: actually they are, but in sqlite (in c++) query is a string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `tags.name` and use this:

```
INSERT  OR IGNORE
INTO    tags (id, name)
VALUES  (NULL, 'tagsName')
```

If for some reason you can't or don't want to do this, use this:

```
INSERT
INTO    tags (id, name)
SELECT  NULL, 'tagsName'
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    tags
        WHERE   name = 'tagsName'
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tags (name)
SELECT 'tagsName'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE name = 'tagsName');
```

OR

```
INSERT  OR IGNORE
INTO tags (id, name)
VALUES (NULL, 'tagsName')
```

if you have a unique constraint